# Deploying Django with Virtualenv, Circus and Chaussette

Tags: python, django, virtualenv, circusd, centos7

I'm trying to run Django with Virtualenv, Circus and Chaussette, in a virtualhost with CentOS 7, but i keep getting this error when i run **circusd circus.ini**:

```
(djenv)[root@localhost django]# circusd circus.ini
2014-09-01 22:06:38 circus[2406] [INFO] Starting master on pid 2406
2014-09-01 22:06:38 circus[2406] [INFO] sockets started
2014-09-01 22:06:38 circus[2406] [WARNING] error in 'settings': [Errno 2] No such file or directory: '~/.virtualenv/djenv/bin/chaussette'
2014-09-01 22:06:38 circus[2406] [WARNING] error in 'settings': [Errno 2] No such file or directory: '~/.virtualenv/djenv/bin/chaussette'
2014-09-01 22:06:38 circus[2406] [WARNING] error in 'settings': [Errno 2] No such file or directory: '~/.virtualenv/djenv/bin/chaussette'
2014-09-01 22:06:38 circus[2406] [WARNING] error in 'settings': [Errno 2] No such file or directory: '~/.virtualenv/djenv/bin/chaussette'
2014-09-01 22:06:38 circus[2406] [WARNING] error in 'settings': [Errno 2] No such file or directory: '~/.virtualenv/djenv/bin/chaussette'
2014-09-01 22:06:38 circus[2406] [INFO] settings stopped
2014-09-01 22:06:38 circus[2406] [INFO] Arbiter now waiting for commands
2014-09-01 22:06:38 circus[2406] [INFO] circusd-stats started
2014-09-01 22:06:38 circus[2415] [INFO] Starting the stats streamer

# Here i close circusd with ctrl+c

2014-09-01 22:19:40 circus[2406] [INFO] Got signal SIG_INT
2014-09-01 22:19:40 circus[2406] [INFO] Arbiter exiting
2014-09-01 22:19:41 circus[2406] [INFO] circusd-stats stopped
Exception ignored in: <module 'threading' from '/usr/local/lib/python3.4/threading.py'>
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.4/threading.py", line 1294, in _shutdown
    t.join()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.4/threading.py", line 1057, in join
    raise RuntimeError("cannot join current thread")
RuntimeError: cannot join current thread
```

The path to my django project is **/opt/webapps/django/**. This is the structure of that path:

(FYI: settings was the name i gave to my django project)

```
/django/
/django/manage.py
/django/circus.ini
/django/settings/
/django/settings/urls.py
/django/settings/wsgi.py
/django/settings/settings.py
```

The path to my virtualenv is: **~/.virtualenv/djenv/**. This is the structure (bin) of that path:

```
/djenv/
/djenv/bin/
/djenv/bin/circusd
/djenv/bin/chaussette
/djenv/bin/circushttpd
/djenv/bin/python3.4
/djenv/bin/pip
```

The content of my **circus.ini** is:

```
[circus]
endpoint = tcp://127.0.0.1:5555
pubsub_endpoint = tcp://127.0.0.1:5556
stats_endpoint = tcp://127.0.0.1:5557

[watcher:settings]
cmd = ~/.virtualenv/djenv/bin/chaussette django:/opt/webapps/django --fd $(circus.sockets.settings)$ --django-settings settings.settings
use_sockets = True
numprocesses = 3

[socket:settings]
host = 0.0.0.0
port = 8080
```

Comment: Instead of `~`, use the full path to your environment.

Comment: Already tried that, but i keep getting the same error.

Comment: After all i actually needed to change ~ for the full path (/root/). Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So i finally find a solution. Here is what i did.

First i changed my circus.ini to this:

```
[circus]
endpoint = tcp://127.0.0.1:5555
pubsub_endpoint = tcp://127.0.0.1:5556
stats_endpoint = tcp://127.0.0.1:5557

[watcher:settings]
cmd = /root/.virtualenvs/djenv/bin/chaussette settings.wsgi.application
args = --fd $(circus.sockets.settings)
use_sockets = True
numprocesses = 3
copy_env = True
virtualenv = /root/.virtualenvs/djenv/

[socket:settings]
host = 0.0.0.0
port = 8080
```

Because i'm running this circus in python 3.4.1 i was getting another error:

```
OSError: [Errno 9] Bad file descriptor
```

Looking for a solution to this problem i found this fix https://github.com/mozilla-services/circus/pull/800/files

Hope this helps others.

Comment: If you run this code with Python 3.5.1 expect to get this error

TypeError: get() got an unexpected keyword argument 'raw'.

The solution has being published here: https://github.com/circus-tent/circus/commit/d0d2ac4fd843bb9f050a8c678956fe3682371001

just add **kwargs as suggested in /path/to/virtualenv/lib/python3.5/site-packages/circus/config.py

Comment: for someone who is trying to use circus on production you can have a look at this post (http://aameer.github.io/circus-as-an-alternative-to-supervisor/) which may help.Thanks

Answer (score 2):

This reply is **too** late but maybe will be useful for other. Now working with python3.4 and django1.9

Here is my /etc/circus/circusd.ini

```
[circus]
check_delay = 5
include_dir = /etc/circus/conf.d
logoutput = /var/log/circus/system.log
statsd = True

[plugin:flapping]
use = circus.plugins.flapping.Flapping
```

And my project /etc/circus/conf.d/project.ini

```
[project_name]
cmd = chaussette project_name.wsgi.application --backend waitress --fd $(circus.sockets.project_name)
use_sockets = True
virtualenv = /path/to/env  # if you are using virtualenv
working_dir = /path/to/project
copy_env = True

stdout_stream.class = FileStream
stdout_stream.filename = /path/to/logs/stdout.log
stdout_stream.refresh_time = 0.3

stderr_stream.class = FileStream
stderr_stream.filename = /path/to/logs/error.log
stderr_stream.refresh_time = 0.3

[project_name]
PYTHONPATH  = /path/to/project

[socket:project_name]
host = localhost
port = 8000
```

Take care of permission on /path/to/logs/ and /var/log/circus/system.log. Directories should exists.